# How to make my path-finding algorithm not go in reverse?

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

My path-finding method is given two objects containing an id, name, x/y coordinates, and path stored in an Array List. The path data is the id of each object that it can directly connect to. The objective is to call my method recursively until it finds its goal using the shortest distance, and when it reaches the end it returns true.

The problem:
If the distance to the node that you came from is shorter than the other nodes in the current nodes path, then it will cause an infinite loop bouncing back and forth between the two nodes. I have struggled with this problem for several hours and could be over thinking it. Any advice or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

The Algorithm:

```
while (!pathfound) {
    current = findPath(current, end);
}

public static Place findPath(Place curPlace, Place endPlace) {
    ArrayList<Integer> path = curPlace.path;
    int id;
    double lastdist = 999;
    double distance;
    Place bestPlace = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
        id = curPlace.path.get(i);
        distance = distance(getPlace(id), curPlace)
                + distance(getPlace(id), endPlace);
        if (distance < lastdist) {
            bestPlace = getPlace(id);
        } 

        lastdist = distance;
    }

    if (result.length() == 0) {
        result += bestPlace.name;
    } else {
        result += ", " + bestPlace.name;
    }

    System.out.println("CURCITY: " + bestPlace.id);
    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println(lastdist);

    if (bestPlace == endPlace) {
        pathfound = true;
    }

    return bestPlace;
}
```

You can ignore result, it is for keeping up with the nodes that are passed through. If there are any other details you would like to know, please ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is acceptable to modify `Place` you can add a boolean "visited" flag. Reset them all to false prior to running the algorithm; set to true when you visit and false when you leave (don't forget to unset them on the way out of the recursion - if you do this properly you can even avoid having to explicitly reset the flags before starting). Skip nodes where the flag is true.

A more short-sighted option is to pass the last visited `Place` as a parameter to the function, and skip that one. This will not prevent larger loops but may be entirely appropriate for your situation and is the simplest to implement.

Both of the above are O(1) with minimal overhead. If you cannot modify `Place` you could store a `Set` of visited places (remove them from the set on the way out of recursion), and skip places that are already in that set. Depending on your performance requirements, if you use a `HashSet` you will want to come up with an appropriate hashing function.

Along those lines, at the expense of more memory, if your ID numbers are unique and cover a reasonably sized finite range, a `boolean[]` indexed by ID number is a constant time alternative to a set here (it is essentially the "visited" flag option with the flags stored externally).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help! I can modify Place and I actually was trying to do something similar with a boolean flag and an extra method for checking if visited. I'm worried this is going to cause the same problems. I kept getting null pointers because of bestPlace being set inside the loop and then being used by result. It could be that my logic is off, but I'm not sure exactly how to structure the code with a flag.

Comment: @billabrian6 I would also recommend using the `Set` of visited `Places`.

Comment: @billabrian6 You haven't posted your full recursive algorithm so it is hard to give any more specific advice. Generally, with the flag approach, the recursive function would first check the flag, then if it is false, set it to true, then set it to false again before returning. The flag essentially means "is there a recursive function on the stack right now that is referencing this place". I agree with ggovan, though; a `Set` of visited places is robust and clear.

Comment: @ggovan and Jason C Thanks for your input! I was able to solve this problem with the advice of both of you. I used a set and added the current place at the start of the algorithm, then I looped through the path to see if it existed inside the path. If it existed in the path i simply removed it. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

Using a recursive approach to path finding algorithm can be quite tricky, as you always need some kind of global information to evaluate, which one of two paths is more suitable. While following a single path, you can never be sure, if it is the right one. Even if you always follow the nearest node, it doesn't have to be the right path. This is called [best-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search) strategy and although it is not the best, it can be made to work, but you have to make sure to try other paths as well, because you can't pull it off by simply always sticking to the closest node.

If you want to do a path finding algorithm, you will need to keep track of all the nodes, that you have already explored exhaustively and therefore will never need to visit again. This can be done either explicitly, by storing the list of visited nodes in a structure of some kind, or you can be smarter about it and enforce this by good design of policy for selecting a new node to be visited.

In other words, if you keep track of the nodes to be visited along with the distances to each node ([priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue)) and you always make sure to visit the nearest not-yet-visited node, you will never revisit the same nodes again, without having to explicitly enforce it, such as in [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a), or [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try and help me!